# Postfix not sending mail using specific outgoing ip address

Tags: postfix, smtp, pacemaker

I have a cluster set-up using pacemaker/corosync and have some fail over IPs set-up. I have designated postfix to use ome of those failover IPs using:-

smtp_bind_address = aa.bb.cc.dd

in main.cf

However, when I send a test mail to my google a/c I'm receiving the mail from actual server ip address instead of the ip address above.

Does anyone know what could be causing this please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want `smtp_bind_address`, but most likely did not set `inet_interfaces` (inet_interfaces=all or inet_interfaces=eth1)

Make that change, then stop/start postfix. You can't just reload if you're changing inet_interfaces. Postfix ignores any bind configuration, if interfaces is empty (or not set).